# Make one member function equal another

Tags: c++, function, class, member

Lets say I have class test_1, and in that class I have a public function foo_1.

Later, in main, I create two objects (A,B) of class test_1. And for object A I need foo_1 to do this: a + b, and for object B I need foo_1 to do: a - b.
Maybe later I will create object C, and I will need his foo_1 to perform: 2.0*a.

But that's not all))
I could have created functions boo_1, boo_2, boo_3 to perform the tasks I need, and make foo_1 a pointer, and do something like:

```
A.foo_1 = &boo_1 ;
B.foo_1 = &boo_2 ;
C.foo_1 = &boo_3 ;
```

But. I have another class test_2, objects of that class need to use function foo_1 from a specific objects of class test_1.

Can I somehow create different bodies for a foo_1 function, depending on the object?
And then assign objct.foo_1 of class test_1 to objct.foo_2 of class test_2?
Or will I need to create boo_# functions and later do smth like this:

```
class test_1{
public:
void (*foo_1)(int);
};

class test_2{
public:
void (*foo_2)(int);
};

void boo_1(int);
void boo_2(int);
void boo_3(int);

int main{

test_1 A,B,C ;
A.foo_1 = &boo_1 ;
B.foo_1 = &boo_2 ;
C.foo_1 = &boo_3 ;

test_2 AA, BB, CC;
AA.foo_2 = &boo_1 ;
BB.foo_2 = &boo_2 ;
CC.foo_2 = &boo_3 ;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"I have a couple of questions"_ That's a bad start for asking on Stack Overflow.

Comment: What you really need is POLYMORPHISM, search for C++ pure abstract classes and virtual base classes.

Comment: @πάντα ε: I agree, but as far as I understand it it is actually only one question.

Comment: @Aswin Murugesh: Did you really mean overloading? Or overriding?

Comment: `std::function` may be an alternative to function pointer.

Comment: @MikeMB: Sorry. After reading the question very clearly, I feel it does not fall in any of the two categories?